# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to load around 6000 - 8000 rows in a UITableview. I get the data from the server using a async call and when I get the data I call

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

This is to refresh the table view . But because of some reason my app gets stuck and freezes . 
When I debug , I found that cellforrowatindexpath is called 6000 times (on main thread) and 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier always returns null .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       CDTableRowCell *cell = nil;

        // Create and Resue Custom ViewCell
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // got into render/theme objec 
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[CDTableRowCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

// MODIFYING CELL PROPERTIES HERE FROM AN ARRAY
// NO HTTP CALLS 

}
```

Also, tableview  starts reusing cell once I start scrolling but before that I never always create a new one.
Any clue why this strange  behavior  ???

Comment: Any chance you're telling the tableview that each row has a height of 0? This behavior can be explained if it thinks all cells should be visible.

Comment: @KevinBallard let me check that

Comment: @KevinBallard

I tried this but does not seems to work


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 40;
}

Comment: is the view controller a tableviewcontroller (default) or a viewcontroller with a table embedded?

Comment: @mkral tableview embedded in a viewcontroller ... The height of tableview is Autoresizing depending upon the parent

Comment: Are you resizing the frame of the cell in the CDTableRowCell ?

Comment: Also check the size of your tableview frame

Comment: Yes I am .. Is that a problem ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16117/discussion-between-kunal-balani-and-mkral)

Comment: Are you doing it in init? if so try resizing it in `-(void)layoutSubviews`

Comment: @KunalBalani: That's the problem. Your autosized tableview is tall enough to show all 6000 rows at once. It's waaaaaaayyy too large.

Comment: The hight of tableview is 704 .. I used NSLog to print its size before reloadData is called

Comment: @KevinBallard I tried by removing Autoreszing mask but that did not help .. :(

Comment: Any chance the table view that's sending the original `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and the `tableView` instance referred to in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are different instances? Also, in chat you said you're subclassing UITableView. What are you overriding there?

Comment: I know it's been awhile since we last talked but it bugged me still. Look at your Cell in `layoutSubviews` and make sure that `[super layoutSubviews];` is called first.

Comment: You should stop leaving us hanging on this one :) please share with us some more of your code. Also, what's the purpose of redirecting the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: I did , still have the same issue.

Comment: I dont think so , because when I use NSLog statements in this function. I see that this is being called several times and this function is the one which blocks my main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The method in your question is not a table view datasource method. The datasource method has the table view as an argument. The method you have written is one that can be used to obtain a cell from the tableView itself, not to obtain a new cell from the datasource.

I don't know how often that method is called but overriding it is almost certainly not what you want to do.

I'm guessing you have subclassed a uitableview to be its own datasource? If so, you need to have the code in your question in the datasource method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and not override the method as you have now.

Comment: is right - You should also consider using an NSFetchedResultsController to manage the data rather than processing 6000 rows - whilst complex, the NSFetchedResultsController is a very smart way of getting some responsiveness into your app.

Comment: Thanks - you're right - I realised this after posting but couldn't figure out how to move my "comment"